# No automatic line break when exceeding textarea in form input field

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a form with an input field for a string. I resized the 'textarea' height to fit with the style I'm trying to achieve but I found two unexpected problems which I haven't been able to fix.

1. The text input and placeholder values are centred vertically in the textarea. I'd like them to be rendered on the top of the 'textarea'.
   I've tried modifying margins and paddings of the element and its parents without success.
2. When the text input exceeds the 'textarea' horizontally, it is rendered in a long single line instead of being broken into new lines as I'd like it to be.
   I've tried adding `overflow-x: scroll;` to the element without success.

What am I missing to achieve the results I'm aiming for?

A relevant segment of my code here

**My form**

```
    <%= simple_form_for(@post, remote: true, html: { class: 'form-inline', id: 'new_post_form'}) do |f| %>
      <div class="form-inputs">
        <%= f.input :content, :label => false, :placeholder => "   Say something here!", :required => true, :autofocus => true, :input_html => { id: "new_post_content_field", class: "garlic-auto-save" } %>

        <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', id: "save-btn", style:'background:transparent' ) do %>
            <br><i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o" aria-hidden="true" title="submit"; data-toggle="tooltip"; data-placement="rigth"></i>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

**application scss**

```
  #new_post_content_field {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
```

}

[image: An image of the form to illustrate the problem here]

PS. I'm using Rails plus Simple Form gem, though I assume this is a pure CSS/HTML issue

**UPDATE: As requested the rendered form**

```
    <div id="new_post_div" class="hide">
      <form class="simple_form form-inline" id="new_post_form" novalidate="novalidate" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/posts" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">

    <div class="form-inputs">
        <div class="form-group string required post_content"><input class="form-control string required garlic-auto-save" id="new_post_content_field" autofocus="autofocus" required="required" aria-required="true" placeholder="   Say something here!" type="text" name="post[content]" data-com.agilebits.onepassword.user-edited="yes"></div>

        <button name="button" type="submit" id="save-btn" style="background:transparent">
            <br><i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o" aria-hidden="true" title="" ;="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="rigth" data-original-title="submit"></i>
        </button>    </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you post the rendered HTML please?

Comment: Sure Michael, thanks I'll post it now

Comment: Michael thanks a lot for your help, but no need to dig into the code. Li has pointed out the issue and solution through Rails Simple Form Gem. In any case thanks for your interest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not look like a `textarea` but a `input` with `text` type.

Base on the Simple Form's documentation, https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form

> For example, a column created with type :text in the database will use a textarea input by default.

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :description, as: :text %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

try to add `as: :text` to your `simple_form_for` helper.

Comment: That was the case Li thanks a lot. I thought it was something like that but I was lazy enough to change the attribute type in my DB to check. I didn't know you could change it such easily with Simple From. Very helpful thanks a lot!